# problem with merging branch to trunk?

Tags: tortoisesvn

Just now I tried to merge my branch to the trunk with the following handlings:

1. Update the working copy of the trunk
2. Merge->reintegrate

Then the folder of the working copy of the trunk gets the conflicting sign. By means of Check for modifications I get a list which contains a lot files and even the folder of the trunk copy. Beside the list a window with the title "svn_mergeinfo-TortoiseMerge" appears. This window displays two panels, svn:mergeinfo:Working Base and svn:mergeinfo: Working Copy. In the Working Copy panel there is a file with some numbers, perhaps versions, aheaded with a plus sign. Its counterpart in the Working Base panel is gray blank. Most of them have been found not modified at all.

What are the wrongings I have done? 
How could I get rid of the issue?

Thanks a lot in advance.

John

Answer (score 0):

The svn:mergeinfo property is set so Subversion can help you track which revisions have been merged into the trunk or a particular branch. This is normal, and harmless, as it does not affect file contents. For instance, TortoiseSVN uses this to gray out revisions that have already been merged in the GUI for convenience.

Check out this link for more information => [svn:mergeinfo](http://www.collab.net/community/subversion/articles/merge-info.html)

Comment: could I commit my reintegrated working copy of trunk without caring about these supposedly modified folder and files?

Comment: You can commit the re-integrated working copy. You may wish to commit the svn:mergeinfo property at least on the top-level folder (e.g. trunk/) but it should not be set on any other file/folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. How could I disable such a kind of property commit?

Comment: Check this question out => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767418/remove-unnecessary-svnmergeinfo-properties

Comment: Thanks again. Justnow I read thru the recommended posting. There are still two questions on my side.
Is it harmful to remove the svn:mergeinfo in property?
Why some of the files containing such properties, but the other not?

Comment: In my limited experience, it hasn't been harmful to remove the property if it got accidentally added to any folder/file below the checkout level. Probably a good idea to check out the svn book..

Answer (score 0):

Seems that changes in trunk and branch can not be merged automatically. (Did somebody or you modify trunk after branch has been made?) Suppose, you need to merge it manually, with the help of mdiff tool for example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Update had been carried first before my reintegation.

Do you mean, I have to commit the changes in my trunk copy manually?

Comment: I think you need to merge changes from branch to trunk manually. Actually, even in case there are obvious and little changes in branch or tag, I've never used automatic merging. I use merging tool with GUI and this gives more ways to control over the results.

Comment: Anyway, this may be helpful: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html