# Get conflict on unchanged file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a trunk folder for main line development and a branch folder for specific feature development. I did before 2 month a merge from trunk to brunch and it worked well.

Now, I want merge again from trunk to brunch but I get numerous conflicts also on files that were not changed in the brunch since the last merge.
For example: I get a conflict on image file that wasn't changed in trunk and in brunch since the last merge.

More one example: I get a conflict on a file that was changed in trunk with some revisions since the last merge but it was not changed in brunch.
What can be the reason of getting numerous conflicts on unchanged files?

Answer (score 1):

Do those files and directories have the svn:mergeinfo property set from a previous merge?
http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html

This talks about how to delete them. 
[Remove unnecessary svn:mergeinfo properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767418/remove-unnecessary-svnmergeinfo-properties)