# Red overlays on Untouched files after merging

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I was trying to merge some of the revisions from a Branch, say B_1.1 to trunk. Following things were observed,

1. Some conflicts occured.
2. `Test Merge/Merge` has completes as expected.

When I have done a `Check for modification`, it has observed that three files are shown with tortoise svn red overlay.

1. I haven't edited those files.
2. which are not coming under the selected revisions.
3. Which were not there in the Merge log.
4. Did a `Compare with Base` - Both `Working copy` and `working base` looks exactly same except the working copy has a cursor blinking at End of file.

What is the meaning of this wiered behaviour?

`Tortoise Version 1.6.16`

Comment: In Check for Modifications, do `text status` or `property status` show `Modified`? Are you really using TortoiseSVN 1.16? If there even was a version with that number (and I don't think there was), it's so old that you shouldn't even try to use it.

Comment: It was a typo. Version was 1.6.16. Thanks @alroc for pointing that.

Comment: Then I would recommend upgrading to a supported release (1.8.x preferably, but 1.7.x is still supported). You haven't answered my first question, but 1.6.x created "spurious" `svn:mergeinfo` data, causing what you're likely observing, which was resolved in 1.7.x

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would svn merge of a branch with no changes causes untouched files to modify svn:mergeinfo property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051267/why-would-svn-merge-of-a-branch-with-no-changes-causes-untouched-files-to-modify)

Comment: `Compare with base` did not have any differences, when I close that window, the `mergeinfo` will be displayed which was a blank one. Let me go through the link you provided. Thanks.

Comment: But what does Check for Modifications show you has changed? Text Status or Property Status?

Comment: I think it was showing `modified`. I have already reverted those back.