# SVN mergeinfo property and branches

Tags: svn, merge, branch

Here we go again with svn:mergeinfo. I have read all the Q/A regarding it but I have come across a case that does not seem to be covered in the existing posts here.
My trunk is clean of svn:mergeinfo, i.e. this:

```
svn propget svn:mergeinfo --depth=infinity
```

returns only merge info in the root of trunk, which is fine.
The I create a branch, and that branch is fine too, with svn:mergeinfo only at the root of the branch. But then I try to update the branch with the latest trunk like so:

```
svn merge http://xxxxx/trunk
```

And then a bunch of files (60 or so) get the svn:mergeinfo property added. Please note that I had this problem earlier when the 60 files had the mergeinfo property set on trunk, and I deleted it from the trunk, and then branched off the trunk.
So the properties are not on the trunk, not on the branch, they appear magically whenever I update the branch with the trunk.

Any ideas?

Comment: Actually you shouldn't have to do anything about `svn:mergeinfo`. It's just there and __it is updated by `svn merge`,__ so, yes, it appears after merging. That's what it is there for. What's your problem with `svn merge` adding merge info?

Comment: Which release of SVN client/server are you using?

Comment: One by one: svn client: svn, version 1.6.11 (r934486)
svn server: 1.6.6 (r40053)

Comment: My problem with svn:mergeinfo being added is twofold:
1) This was removed from the trunk completely in the 60-odd files that had it initially (due to a partial branch commit) and so I have no idea how is that still being introduced
2) It clutters the output of svn status and even worse: it complicates merges back to trunk enormously since svn declares the svn:mergeinfo as conflicts

Comment: Just so that this is clear: I had a bunch (60 odd) sparse files containing the svn:mergeinfo property in my trunk. This was a pain to carry whenever merging back branches. I removed all svn:mergeinfo properties from the trunk and then branched. The branch contains no svn:mergeinfo at all (except for the root), but when I update the branch with the trunk all those mergeinfo properties that were gone both from the branch and from the trunk now appear again.

Answer (score 2):

This is svn 1.5 bug.
[SVN Mergeinfo properties on paths other than the working copy root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391864/svn-mergeinfo-properties-on-paths-other-than-the-working-copy-root)

Try to remove them:

> Useful commands Get mergeinfo on all
>   tree, the XML format is needed to
>   create readable output: svn propget
>   svn:mergeinfo --recursive --xml
>
> Delete mergeinfo on tree except root
>   (the merge target) svn propdel
>   --recursive svn:mergeinfo ./*

read more: [Remove unnecessary svn:mergeinfo properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767418/remove-unnecessary-svnmergeinfo-properties)