# tortoisesvn svn:mergeinfo changing extra files for merges only on a single pc

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging, visualsvn

There are lots of posts with questions about why you see changes on files that include only the mergeinfo changing when performing branching and merging.  They all point to one thing: svn:mergeinfo property being set on the directory or file.  Examples: [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767418/remove-unnecessary-svnmergeinfo-properties), [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391864/svn-mergeinfo-properties-on-paths-other-than-the-working-copy-root), [(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622409/tortoisesvn-using-svnmergeinfo-is-there-a-way-to-turn-it-off) etc.

I have 10-15 files in our production environment where this regularly occurs.  I am going to remove this property on these files.  What I cannot figure out is why this behavior only occurs on my machine.  We have 7 active devs branching and merging on our repository on a weekly basis and to my knowledge, only my branching and merging causes these unnecessary mergeinfo property changes to occur.

I will remove the mergeinfo property but it won't tell me: **WHY ONLY ME?!**  Any ideas?

I am running TortoiseSVN 1.7.10 and VisualSVN 2.5.2 against a subversion 1.7.7 repository.

Comment: Do you work on the same SVN branch as others? Maybe only yours is "affected".

Comment: Yes, I frequently work on branches with other devs.  The issue occurs on any branches I do merges to/from with my PC it seems.  It's happened on branches that I've created and ones that other's have created.  It doesn't happen on every single merge, but I'd probably 50%.